# Show full dateTime in grid c#

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a value of for example `07-August-2012 09:30:00` with the full date and time in my `DateTime`, but there is only `07.08.2012` displayed in my infragistics ultra grid cell when I set it value to this `DateTime`.

How can I display the full `DateTime` value?

Comment: check link of answer which is alaredy exists on SO ...check link in my answer..

Answer (score 5):

In `InitializeLayout` event of your UltraGrid do:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, 
  Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["yourDateCol"].Format = "G"; //MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
}
```

for complete reference see: 
[Localizing Cell Display Format](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/WinGrid_Localizing_Cell_Display_Format.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the column with this code in the **InitializeLayout** event

```
    public static void FormatAsDate(UltraGridColumn cl)
    {
        cl.CellAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Left;
        cl.Header.Appearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Left;
        cl.MaskInput = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        cl.PromptChar = ' ';
        cl.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DateWithoutDropDown;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show your full date time Value would be using the correct format. If you would like to have it exactly like 07-August-2012 09:30:00 you could set the following format of the desired column in the InitializeLayout event of your UltraGrid control like:

```
   `private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["DesireColumnKey"].Format = "dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    }   `
```